# Web Audio API does not work on iOS device (Cordova Project)

Tags: ios, cordova, html5-audio

I have this function on my project

```
function createAudio(src) {

    var fullNode = "<audio controls loop hidden id='soundAudioTag'> <source type='audio/mpeg' src='" + src + "'/></audio>";

    if(/.mp3/.test(src)) {
        $('.content').eq(0).append(fullNode);
        $('#soundAudioTag').trigger("play");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It just properly works on Browser, Android webview and iOS simulator webview. But for some reason there's no audio output on a real iOS device. No error log, everything just goes as expected. My audio element is playing but theres no audio.

- WKWebView is not an alternative for me
- Already test on another device
- Device is not mute

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having this same problem with cordova 4.5.2 on a device only.  It works correctly in the simulator.

Comment: @AleksG i was trying to run .OGG sound files. iOS webview don't suport .ogg. Use mp3

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using MP3. The app works correctly in mobile Safari and in simulator, but not as a Cordova app on real device.

Comment: @AleksG oooh really. i answered you thinking about the issue i had before this one. in this case i just give up. i have published my app anyway. sometimes it works in some devices sometimes it does not (most part of time)

Comment: @AleksG if you find out the problem please hint me anyway